# Is there a way to fix all eslint errors?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am getting the following error:

`Line 1:1:  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/href-no-hash' was not found  jsx-a11y/href-no-hash`

I have tried:

```
npm i -g eslint

eslint --fix .
```

Plus I have tried upgrading and downgrading the eslint package, it didn't seem to do anything.
But I still get the same error. It is throwing that, out of nowhere in all my react components

This appeared after I started the nodemon "npm run dev" to start my local server server.js file.

Here are my dependencies:

```
 "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
```

Found this in my package.json

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
```

.eslintrc.json file config:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            "tab"
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "windows"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "double"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve]. Show your eslint configuration? Does it mention that rule? If so, why did you add it? Were you following some instructions? Did you skip a bit where they explained how to add support for that rule? Have you typed the rule's name into Google to get any clues about how to configure it?

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for your answer Quentin. I am new to this, I haven't created any eslint configuration. I can't find them in my code. In the tutorial they didn't mention any eslint configs. He went straight to the server.js file and his ran just fine

Comment: eslint is **not** going to be checking for a rule named `jsx-a11y/href-no-hash` by default. There must be a configuration *somewhere*

Comment: Alright, thank you for clarifying. Now, I don't find the configs file, should I google how to create one? What do you recommend? Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you are running two things together that are not playing nicely. What are your dependencies in your package.json?

Comment: @epascarello 
I-ve added them to my question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y` in the package.json file.

In case it doesn't work, please share your complete eslint configuration.

Also, one thing to mention, I searched for your issue and I found out that there are some breaking changes with this library/package. If you get any other error after adding this in package.json, try downgrading the package to some stable version.

P.S. In case nothing works, You may find some help [here](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/283).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To what part of my package.json file should I had that?

Comment: I just added my config to the question, if possible, please take a look.

Comment: @TomasMota I literally didn't mean that you've to write `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`, I meant that you need to install it via `npm` or `yarn` whatever you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, so in my case, I don't know if this had anything to do with it or I was just lucky.

This was all being thrown after I added this to my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
```

Now, it showed a dotted line under the require word. It said that I needed to change the way I imported express.

I clicked on `quick fix` and it turned it to

`import express from 'express';`
Boom error went away, no more warnings and the nodemon server.js file is working perfectly.